# Extracting Color Attributes from CSS

Tags: ios, css, xamarin, uicolor, pixate

is it possible to extract Colors for certain CSS-Classes or id's as UIColor in Xamarin.
In my default.css I would create an id like this:

```
#colorid { color: #FFF; }
```

And then access the Color kind of like this:

```
UIColor color = SomePixateClass.UIColorFromId("colorid");
```

Comment: Do you have a CSS parser class?

Comment: It's easy if you do have an element with that ID in your DOM tree.